# C++/openCV: Can not open camera

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, beagleboneblack

I try to capture single frames from an USB camera with openCV on the Beaglebone Black.

First my setup:
I have a Debian 7 VM with Qt to cross compile.
I am using Qt 5.2
On the Beaglebone I run Debian 7 too.
I builded openCV 2.4.1 and 2.4.9 in the VM and on the BBB (http://aplacetogeek.wordpress.com/qt-opencv-v4l-cross-compiling-raspberry-pi-beagle-bone/)

If I compile in VM I can capture pictures. If I compile for the BBB it fails to open the camera-device.

Here the method (just for testing, I know it is aweful^^):

```
cv::VideoCapture * cam0 = new cv::VideoCapture(0);

if (cam0->isOpened())
{
    cam0->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
    cam0->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
    cam0->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'));
    cam0->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 5);
}
else
{
    qDebug()<<"Could not open cam0";
    delete cam0;
    cam0 = NULL;
}

cv::VideoCapture * cam1 = new cv::VideoCapture(1);
if (cam1->isOpened())
{
    cam1->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
    cam1->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
    cam1->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'));
    cam1->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 5);
}
else
{
    qDebug()<<"Could not open cam1";
    delete cam1;
    cam1 = NULL;
}

qDebug()<<"Here I am! :)";

if ((cam0 != NULL) || (cam1 != NULL))
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        QString num;
        num = QString::number(i);

        if (cam0 != NULL)
        {
            cam0->grab();
            if (cam0->retrieve(frame))
            {
                QString vm0("/home/administrator/Bilder/0captured_yay"+num+".jpg");
                QString bbb0("/home/debian/pics/0captured_yay"+num+".jpg");

                qDebug()<<"Write "<<bbb0;
                cv::imwrite(vm0.toStdString(), frame);
                cv::imwrite(bbb0.toStdString(), frame);
            }
            else
                qDebug()<<"cam0: Could not grab frame "<<i+1;
        }

        if (cam1 != NULL)
        {
            cam1->grab();
            if (cam1->retrieve(frame))
            {
                QString vm1("/home/administrator/Bilder/1captured_yay"+num+".jpg");
                QString bbb1("/home/debian/pics/1captured_yay"+num+".jpg");

                qDebug()<<"Write "<<bbb1;
                cv::imwrite(vm1.toStdString(), frame);
                cv::imwrite(bbb1.toStdString(), frame);
            }
            else
                qDebug()<<"cam1: Could not grab frame "<<i+1;
        }

        this->thread()->sleep(1);
    }
}
```

In the VM it works fine an writes the pictures. But on the BBB I just get the output:

```
Could not open cam0 
Could not open cam1 
Here I am! :) 
Here I go... :(
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like what was happening to me when I was first introduced to FPGA emulators. Not all the time will a certain feature work on the actual device that worked in the emulator. My first suggestion is to try working directly on the bone this time - there may have been a compile issue not seen/ignored on the VM, or the path to the camera has changed. The alternative would be to use something like ROS.

Comment: cv::VideoCapture(0); the id of devices may be different than 0 or 1 in usage, try to find ids of cameras